# Get Off Your Knees

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "Get Off Your Knees" mean "hurt you"? Simply a guess here. I googled it and it offered me with "'Get Off Your Knees: The John Robinson Story' explores the experiences and life of John Robinson and his family, teachers and friends, as they move through the narrative about John's life as a person with a disability."  The best guess I got now it that this hero walks on his knees but he braces himself for the hardship and finally succeeds.

So I deduced that is like Isaac Newton's idea of standing on the shoulders of giants to look further, human race should get off the kneeling knees and stand up.

I am not sure I've got it.

> Saturn–Moon Matrix
> The Moon Matrix is introduced in Human Race **Get Off Your Knees**: The Lion Sleeps No More (2010), in which Icke suggests that the Earth and the collective human mind are manipulated from the Moon, a spacecraft and inter-dimensional portal the reptilians control.

> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Icke#Saturn%E2%80%93Moon_Matrix)

Comment: David Icke's book is called *Human Race Get Off Your Knees*. It literally means "stand up" or in other words, "you can do better."

Comment: "on your knees" means to be submissive to some other power.  "On your feet" means to be independent.